# Find order of pole $\frac{e^z -1}{z^2 +4}$, about $z=2i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

$$\frac{e^z -1}{z^2 +4},\quad\text{about $z=2i$.}$$
The textbook I'm reading isn't specific about these case, only gives basic examples.
Basically to find pole I'd have to expand a Laurent series about some point, in this case $z=2i$, I did $$ \frac{e^{2i} e^{z-2i} -1}{(z-2i)^2 +4-(4z-4)}$$ and from there just expanded $e^{z-2i}$ as a series, just see which powers (without caring about constants) of $z-2i$ was left after canceling, giving me a pole of order 2. Answer however says of order 1.

Comment: $$\frac{e^z-1}{z^2+4}=\frac{\frac{e^z-1}{z+2i}}{z-2i}=\frac{h(z)}{z-2i}$$ with $h(2i) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$z^2+4$ has in $2i$ a simple zero and $e^{2i}-1 \ne 0$, hence $2i$ is a simple pole of $\displaystyle\frac{e^z -1}{z^2 +4}$.

Comment: Thank you again Fred. If the numerator was $=  0$, then what would we have to do? Say $\frac{z^3-1}{(z-1)^3}$ at z = 1

Comment: nevermind, I understand why you cared about the numerator. in this case, it would e $\frac{0}{0^3}$ and have one of the pole order is removable singularity, so pole would be order of 2.

Comment: $\frac{z^3-1}{(z-1)^3}=\frac{z^2+z+1}{(z-1)^2}$, hence $\frac{z^3-1}{(z-1)^3}$ has in $1$ a pole of order $2$.